# How to show single value of array using for loop in mail function?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, email

I am using the mail function to send the form details directly in mail. There is a option in which user can attach 20 images which i can send in mail . Attachments are going , but i have to show image name in front of specific measurement.

> http://netraserve.com/copycat/

above is the site , in which when we click Get a quote a form appears ,then in the end of form there is how many parts ? option . When some one will select values in that a form appears . I have to send the image name also with measurements.

Below is the code i am using , but doesnt know how to send the particular image name under particular measurement.

```
for($x=1;$x<=count($filteredarray);$x++) {

     $message .= "<p style=".'color:#000;font-size:15px;width:100%;color:red'.">Measurements-" .$x."</p><p style=".'color:#000;font-size:16px;width:100%'.">".$_REQUEST['width'.$x]."X".$_REQUEST['length'.$x]."X".$_REQUEST['height'.$x]."</p><p style=".'color:#000;font-size:16px;width:100%'.">Covered:".$_REQUEST['covered'.$x].",Zippers:".$_REQUEST['zip'.$x].",Velcro:".$_REQUEST['vel'.$x].",Image:";
      }
```

as in the end there is image written. but i have to send image name also. Images are stored in filtered array.

Comment: your going to have to embed the images in the email, and script there location with html

Comment: i have attached the images in the attachment sections of email , but i have to show there name in body section of email . i have stored images in a array. As there are measurement columns of these images , so i just need to show image name infront of particular measurement. As images are stored in an array .

Comment: ok just echo the name, what's the problem